# Closure of the algebra generated by $\{\sin x,1\}$ in $C_{\mathbb{R}}([-\pi,\pi])$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

> let $\mathcal{A}\subset C_{\mathbb{R}}([-\pi,\pi])$ equipped with the $\sup$ norm be a sub-algebra generated by $\{\sin x,1\}$.
>
> What is $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$?

This excerise is suppose to be an application of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem but I'm having trouble seeing what this algebra looks like. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What does Stone-Weierstrass states? So what is the most likely candidate for $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$?

Comment: oh I forgot to mention what is $X$. I will edit it now.

Comment: @Hetebrij at first I thought it suppose to be all of $C_{\mathbb{R}}([-\pi,\pi])$ so the use of SW will be easy but that's clearly not possible because all the function in $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ must hold $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. but I think there's another condition which these functions must hold in order to be in $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$

Comment: @dorsh605, we can apply Stone–Weierstrass if we consider our functions defined on another space. For example, we can see $\sin x$ as function on the unit circumference.

Comment: @quartermind so the result should be that $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is all the continuous functions that hold $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$?

Comment: @dorsh605. Not exactly. Use more symmetries of sine.

Comment: @quartermind if you mean to use the fact that sine is odd function then I don't know if I can conclude that all the functions in $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ are odd because $\mathcal{A}$ is also generated by $1$ which is not odd

Comment: @dorsh605, No, it's little more tricky than oddness. Think of obstacles for $\sin x$ to separate points on $[-\pi,\pi)$ and how we might eliminate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a closed subalgebra $\mathcal L \subset C[-\pi,\pi]$ consisting of such functions $f$, that
$$ f(x) = f(\pi-x),\;\; f(-x)=f(x-\pi) \;\quad\; \forall x\in [0,\tfrac{\pi}{2}].$$
Roughly speaking, this is all symmetries of the sine on $[-\pi,\pi]$. For a function in $\mathcal L$, it's fully determined by the behavior on $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Surely $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal L$.

Define $\Phi\colon \mathcal L \rightarrow C[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by function restriction, i.e.
$\Phi(f) = \left.f\right|_{[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]}$. It's not hard to see that $\Phi$ is isomorphism of algebras plus homeomorphism (as it preserves $\sup$-norm).

Algebra $\mathcal B = \Phi(\mathcal A) \subset C[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ is generated by $\{\sin x, 1\}$ and separates points, since the sine is strictly monotone on $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Hence $\overline{\mathcal B} = C[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ by the Stone—Weierstrass theorem. Applying $\Phi^{-1}$ to the latter equality, we get
$ \overline{\mathcal A} = \mathcal L $.